# Generating SSH keypair with paramiko in Python

Tags: python, python-2.7, paramiko

I am trying to generate a SSH key pair with the python module paramiko. There doesn't seem to be much info about key generation. I've read through the paramiko docs but can't figure out whats wrong. I can generate a private and public key without password encryption. However, when I try to encrypt the private key I get the following error.

**ValueError: IV must be 8 bytes long**

I believe the above error is from pycrypto. I've looked through the relevant code in paramiko.pkey and pycrypto without any luck.

Here is a small example.

```
import paramiko

def keygen(filename,passwd=None,bits=1024):
    k = paramiko.RSAKey.generate(bits)
    #This line throws the error.
    k.write_private_key_file(filename,password = 'cleverpassword')
    o = open(fil+'.pub' ,"w").write(k.get_base64())
```

*traceback*

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/var/mobile/Applications/149E4C21-2F92-4712-BAC6-151A171C6687/Documents/test.py", line 14, in keygen
    k.write_private_key_file(filename,password = 'cleverpassword')
  File "/var/mobile/Applications/149E4C21-2F92-4712-BAC6-151A171C6687/Pythonista.app/pylib/site-packages/paramiko/rsakey.py", line 127, in write_private_key_file
    self._write_private_key_file('RSA', filename, self._encode_key(), password)
  File "/var/mobile/Applications/149E4C21-2F92-4712-BAC6-151A171C6687/Pythonista.app/pylib/site-packages/paramiko/pkey.py", line 323, in _write_private_key_file
    self._write_private_key(tag, f, data, password)
  File "/var/mobile/Applications/149E4C21-2F92-4712-BAC6-151A171C6687/Pythonista.app/pylib/site-packages/paramiko/pkey.py", line 341, in _write_private_key
    data = cipher.new(key, mode, salt).encrypt(data)
  File "/var/mobile/Applications/149E4C21-2F92-4712-BAC6-151A171C6687/Pythonista.app/pylib/site-packages/Crypto/Cipher/DES3.py", line 114, in new
    return DES3Cipher(key, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/var/mobile/Applications/149E4C21-2F92-4712-BAC6-151A171C6687/Pythonista.app/pylib/site-packages/Crypto/Cipher/DES3.py", line 76, in __init__
    blockalgo.BlockAlgo.__init__(self, _DES3, key, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/var/mobile/Applications/149E4C21-2F92-4712-BAC6-151A171C6687/Pythonista.app/pylib/site-packages/Crypto/Cipher/blockalgo.py", line 141, in __init__
    self._cipher = factory.new(key, *args, **kwargs)
ValueError: IV must be 8 bytes long
```

Comment: Can you show the full exception traceback?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

#### The Problem

This looks like a bug in `paramiko`.

If you look at the line that threw the error in `pkey.py`, it is the following line:

```
        data = cipher.new(key, mode, salt).encrypt(data)
```

Let us now look at the lines before it, which set the `mode` by first selecting a `cipher_name`.

```
        # since we only support one cipher here, use it
        cipher_name = list(self._CIPHER_TABLE.keys())[0]
        cipher = self._CIPHER_TABLE[cipher_name]['cipher']
        keysize = self._CIPHER_TABLE[cipher_name]['keysize']
        blocksize = self._CIPHER_TABLE[cipher_name]['blocksize']
        mode = self._CIPHER_TABLE[cipher_name]['mode']
```

Here are the contents of `_CIPHER_TABLE`.

```
_CIPHER_TABLE = {
    'AES-128-CBC': {'cipher': AES, 'keysize': 16, 'blocksize': 16, 'mode': AES.MODE_CBC},
    'DES-EDE3-CBC': {'cipher': DES3, 'keysize': 24, 'blocksize': 8, 'mode': DES3.MODE_CBC},
}
```

Observe how the comment contradicts the code. Two ciphers are available, and the line above which selects the `cipher_name` assumes there is only one.

Based on the error, it appears that `'DES-EDE3-CBC'` is selected. If we look at the comment in `DES3.py`, we see the following requirement for an IV.

```
  IV : byte string
    The initialization vector to use for encryption or decryption.

    It is ignored for `MODE_ECB` and `MODE_CTR`.

    For `MODE_OPENPGP`, IV must be `block_size` bytes long for encryption
    and `block_size` +2 bytes for decryption (in the latter case, it is
    actually the *encrypted* IV which was prefixed to the ciphertext).
    It is mandatory.
```

From paramiko's source, we observe that no `IV` is passed, and hence the error we saw.

#### Workaround

Change the following line in `pkey.py` to hardcode the `'AES-128-CBC'` cipher instead.

```
   # cipher_name = list(self._CIPHER_TABLE.keys())[1]
   cipher_name = 'AES-128-CBC'
```

Comment: Thank you very much. The walk through your thought process was most helpful!